# java.time.LocalDateTime conversion issue if seconds are 00

Tags: datetime, java-8, cxf

My web application is using **Apache CXF and JAVA8**, and facing below error in response if user send `xs:datetime` input(seconds 00) as

```
<urn1:dateTimeVal>2016-04-29T20:00:00</urn1:dateTimeVal>
```

**ERROR :**

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error:
>   cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2016-04-29T20:00' is not a valid value for 
>   'dateTime'.

I debug and analysed that if user send `dateTimeVal` as `2016-04-29T20:00:00` then CXF validations for input are passed and XML value is **UnMarshaled** to `java.time.LocalDateTime` as `2016-05-05T20:00` , and at the time of returning the response, the **Marshaling** error occurs due to loss of seconds part(00).

Any help/hint are appreciated.

**P.S** : You can try with below snippet :

```
   java.time.LocalDateTime dt= java.time.LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.MAY, 5, 20, 00, 00);
   System.out.println(dt);
```

**Note** : Above code sample is just for understanding to print datetime value. But actual return type expected in web application is `java.time.LocalDateTime`

**OUTPUT EXPECTED** : 2016-05-05T20:00:00

**OUTPUT ACTUAL**   : 2016-05-05T20:00

**EDIT** : The binding (JAXB) content for the field is :

```
 @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2016-05-03T05:28:57+05:30", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
    @NotNull
    protected LocalDateTime dateTimeVal;
```

AND `LocalDateTimeAdapter` File is

```
 import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
    import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

    public class LocalDateTimeAdapter
      extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime>
    {
      public static LocalDateTime parse(String value)
      {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeAndZoneformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
        TemporalAccessor ta = null;
        try
        {
          ta = dateTimeformatter.parse(value);
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException ex)
        {
          ta = dateTimeAndZoneformatter.parse(value);
        }
        return LocalDateTime.from(ta);
      }

      public static String print(LocalDateTime value)
      {
        return value.toString();
      }

      public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String value)
      {
        return parse(value);
      }

      public String marshal(LocalDateTime value)
      {
        return print(value);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you converting from LocalDateTime to String using `toString()` at some point?

Comment: No, all the internal conversion is done between CXF and Java only.

Comment: Do you have a jaxb bindings file, jaxb annotations in your pojo, or any kind of marshalling adapter you're not showing us?

Comment: Added the marshalling adapter (LocalDateTimeAdapter) and JAXB binding details in the question.

Answer (score 7):

The problem appears to be in `LocalDateTimeAdapter.print()`.  `LocalDateTime.toString()` omits the seconds when the seconds value is 0.

If you change it to

```
public static String print(LocalDateTime value)
{
    return value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
}
```

it will provide the seconds as well when marshaling.

To see a quick example, note the results of the following snippet:

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2016,1,1,0,0,0,0).toString());
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2016,1,1,0,0,0,0).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

The output it gives is

```
2016-01-01T00:00
2016-01-01T00:00:00
```

In the documentation for `LocalDateTime.toString()` it explains this behavior:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>   
>  - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
>   
>  - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
>   
>  - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
>   
>  - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
>   
>  - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>   
>  The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

Comment: I have added the binding content details in the question. Please refer the **EDIT** : section for details.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use

```
System.out.println (DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format (dt));
```

It gives:

```
2016-05-05T20:00:00
```

Comment: In response it should be returned as `java.time.LocalDateTime` type  but not `String` which is returned using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format (dt)`.

Comment: +1 : Seems, problem is in the `LocalDateTimeAdapter.print` method. `return value.toString()` should be  `return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(value)`; I'll try and see if it works!

Comment: For JAXB you need an Adapter class defined in the XJB binding file. E.g. `<globalBindings generateValueClass="true"><javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime" parseMethod="com.helger.peppol.DateAdapter.getLocalDateTimeFromXSD" printMethod="com.helger.peppol.DateAdapter.getAsStringXSD" /></globalBindings>` (using Joda time instead of Java8 DT). See https://github.com/phax/peppol-commons/tree/master/peppol-commons for the whole project setup.