# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter with optional part

Tags: time, java-8

I have a String representing a date (with or without time) like `13/12/2017` or `13/12/2017 15:39:51`

So i'm trying to use java 8 DateTimeFormatter with optional part.

That code works

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("13/12/2017 15:39:51",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy[ HH:mm:ss]"));
System.out.println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
System.out.println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")));

13/12/2017
15:39:51
```

But I don't understand why that one does not

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("13/12/2017",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy[ HH:mm:ss]"));
```

giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13/12/2017' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-12-13 of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
...
```

And even with

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("13/12/2017",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

it does not work with the same exception.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Use [`parseBest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-)

When you use an optional component, you should parse using `parseBest`. Your application may be working using only `parse`, but then it's only by luck (because you're only parsing full inputs, not partial ones). With `parseBest`, you can properly handle various `TemporalAccessor`, which is the whole reason to use optional.

The decision of which `TemporalAccessor` is returned is rather simple: `parseBest` will try to match each `TemporalQuery` in order of argument. When any matches, the method returns that one. So make sure to go from most precise to less precise. Also, if none were matched, an exception will be thrown.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy[ HH:mm:ss]");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest("13/12/2017", LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
if (temporalAccessor instanceof LocalDateTime) {
  dateTime = (LocalDateTime)temporalAccessor;
} else {
  dateTime = ((LocalDate)temporalAccessor).atStartOfDay();
}
```

Comment: I use that solution for a while now but I noticed a little problem.  If the input date seconds are 00 (`17/01/2018 08:30:00`) it gives me `2018-01-17T08:30` and not `2018-01-17T08:30:00`.  Is there a solution ?

Comment: @tweetysat what you say here above is a formatting issue, not a parsing one. To fix it, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37025877/180719).

Comment: Thanks @Olivier Grégoire.  I fixed it.